# C++ fixed number of vector size as class member

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

I have a class

```
class clsNode
{
private:
   vector<clsNode*>m_Daughters;
```

However, this vector will always contain only 2 clsNode pointer. It should not be dynamic vector, but rather a fixed length array that can hold 2 pointers to 2 clsNodes.

I tried

```
vector<clsNode*>m_Daughters[2];
```

But that threw a lot of compiler errors.

Can somebody tell me how to do that correctly?

Comment: Why use a vector then? Why not `clsNode* m_Daughters[2]`?

Comment: @mwerschy Thank you! Can you make your comment the reply?

Comment: There's two good answers already. Just accept one.

Answer (score 3):

This definition has problem

```
vector<clsNode*> m_Daughters[2];
```

It makes `m_Daughters` as an array of two `vector<clsNode*>` which is far from your purpose.

To set the size, you can use its [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
class clsNode
{
   vector<clsNode*> m_Daughters;
public:
   clsNode() : m_Daughters(2)
   {}
};
```

If the size is constant, you can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
class clsNode
{
   array<clsNode*, 2> m_Daughters;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`vector<clsNode*>m_Daughters[2];` creates an array holding two elements of type `vector<clsNode*>`. To correct this, you can:

- declare the vector `vector<clsNode*> m_Daughters;` and change the constructor of your class to `clsNode() : m_Daughters(2, 0) {} // create a vector holding two objects of type clsNode*`
- no need to have a vector at all, just write `clsNode* m_Daughters[2];` and change the constructor to `clsNode() { m_Daughters[0] = m_Daughters[1] = 0; }`